# how can i Create notification

Tags: android, notifications

how can i create notification
 when the date current equals date in the base data(mysql)
 then the notification created with information.
i dont know how can i create the notification with this setting
please help me it's for project

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(final View view) {
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insert, new Response.Listener<String>() {
@override
public void onResponse(String response) {

}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
Toast.makeText(partietache.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}){

@override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
Map<String, String> para = new HashMap<String , String>();
para.put("taskname", ed1.getText().toString().trim());
para.put("totalwork",ed4.getText().toString().trim());
para.put("datetask",ed2.getText().toString().trim());
para.put("starttime",ed3.getText().toString().trim());
para.put("description",ed5.getText().toString().trim());
return para;

}
};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(partietache.this);
requestQueue.add(request);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Add with Succesful" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
public void run() {
partietache.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@override
public void run() {
finish();
}
});
}

} , 4000);
}
});

@override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
if (not.isChecked()) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Notification " + not.getTextOn().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Notification " + not.getTextOff().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: you need to create notification on server side and fire from there

Comment: how can i create on server

Answer (score 0):

In order to use push notifications you will need to do both server-side and client-side coding. Describing the whole process in detail would be too much for an SO answer, you should take a look at one of the many tutorials available online. [Here's one](http://www.androiddeft.com/2017/11/18/push-notification-android-firebase-php/) to get you started.